# How can I add a Site Actions menu in a SharePoint 2013 full size app

Tags: 2013, javascript, sharepoint-addin

**Question:**

*How can I just add a Site Actions Menu to the default chrome control rendered with the full sitze app?*

**Problem:**

in a SharePoint hosted full size app there is no Site Actions menu.

[image: no Site Actions menu in a full size SharePoint App]

If you want to have the this menu, you have to build your own client chrome control like described here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/fp179916(v=office.15).aspx

with jQuery you can exchange the default chrome control with the new one

The problem is that you lose the default chrome control rendered with all the suite bar links.

[image: you get your own chrome control but lose the default one]

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

---

I assume that you use jQuery!
I expect that you have the following div somewhere on your app page:

```
 <div id="chrome_ctrl_container"></div>
```

Then you build your chrome control like you normally would do and hide your container div.

```
        $('#chrome_ctrl_placeholder').hide();

        var options = {                 
            "settingsLinks": [
                {
                    "linkUrl": "**some URL**",
                    "displayName": "** some link nName**"
                }
            ]
        };

        var nav = new SP.UI.Controls.Navigation(
                                "chrome_ctrl_container",
                                options
                            );
```

instead of showing the chrome control with

```
nav.setVisible(true);
```

you just grab the Site Actions menu from the generated chrome control and move it to the suite bar of the default chrome control of the SharePoint app.

```
 var siteActions = $('div#chrome_ctrl_container div#suiteBarRight span.ms-siteactions-root');
 $('div#suiteBarDelta div#suiteBarRight div#suiteBarButtons').prepend(siteActions);
```

now the chrome control should look something like this

[image: Default chrome control with the custom site Actions menu]